# Importing csv file error 1059

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to import a csv file circa 30GB. I have a MySql server running remotely on a vm. When i try to import the csv file I receive the following error

> is too long 1059

I'm using MySql Workbench to import the csv. I used the import tool and let it create the tables from the csv file.

I assume the error is because the data is too big for the column's datatype? Can I change it and or can it auto truncate it? What can I possibly do for this issue?

EDit:

Full error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Program Files\mysqlworkbench\workbench\wizard_progress_page_widget.py", line 197, in thread_work
    self.func()
  File "D:\Program Files\mysqlworkbench\modules\sqlide_power_import_wizard.py", line 132, in start_import
    retval = self.module.start(self.stop)
  File "D:\Program Files\mysqlworkbench\modules\sqlide_power_import_export_be.py", line 300, in start
    ret = self.start_import()
  File "D:\Program Files\mysqlworkbench\modules\sqlide_power_import_export_be.py", line 438, in start_import
    if not self.prepare_new_table():
  File "D:\Program Files\mysqlworkbench\modules\sqlide_power_import_export_be.py", line 266, in prepare_new_table
    self._editor.executeManagementCommand(""" CREATE TABLE %s (%s)""" % (self._table_w_prefix, ", ".join(["`%s` %s" % (col['name'], col["type"]) for col in self._mapping if col['active'] is True])), 1)
DBError: ('Identifier name \'//www.somesite.com/embed/44bc40f3bc04f65b7a35" frameborder="0" height="481" width="608" scrolling="no\' is too long', 1059)
ERROR: Import data file: ('Identifier name \'//www.somesite.com/embed/44bc40f3bc04f65b7a35" frameborder="0" height="481" width="608" scrolling="no\' is too long', 1059)
Failed
```

Comment: please add the hole error message, there must be an identifier to indicate what ot doesn't like

Comment: *I receive the following error* This is a tiny part of error message only.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the table you are loading.  And the `LOAD FILE` statement being used.

Comment: I don't use that i just created a database and the import tool, it's only like next next and finish